# PHP Anonymus function : define variabel from outside of function

Tags: php

I'm currently implementing a PHP anonymus function.

```
class bar {
  public function foo()
  {
    $start = 1;

    add_one(function() {
      $start++;
    })
  }
} 

function add_one($func) {
  $func();  
}
```

This return an error because $start is actually defined outside from the anonymus function, its not a local variable in the anonymus function. 
anybody can solve this ?, how to pass the value ?

Thanks.

Comment: `add_one(function() use ($start) {
      $start++;
    })` though your function doesn't really do very much

Comment: @MarkBaker Hey Mark. I think variables used via `use` are not passed by reference `use (&$start)`

Comment: Ah, thanks guys, sorry for the duplicate question. I cannot find those question before. @Mark : yeah, that function doesn't really do much, its just a simple example i made imitating the real case. But thanks anyway.